# Node Creation Paths

Tags: nodes, uri

I added a custom node-type (content-type) called Document (for example), i also allowed it to create a menu item for navigation purposes.

Then assigned a non-admin role the permission to create new content/edit own content and delete own content.

But the problem here arises that Drupal is automatically creating the paths to create node page.

In simpler terms, its creating a menu item with the path /node/add/document

but this is something i have to avoid, I instead want something like this /add/document

I can't find any way to do this, a Google search also led to nothing helpful. Is it not possible to customize/modify this behavior? my main problem with the default path structure is the "node" being displayed.

### **UPDATE**

I managed to find a way to make the path work with my choice of path structure by going to the URL aliases section (admin / config /search / path ), and assigning the old path a new alias, but like i guessed its still letting me access the add page with the "node" intact as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's by design... You can able to access path using normal path and aliased path...

However, you can change this behaviour using [Global Redirect](https://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module which redirects to aliased path if available...

Project page says

> Once enabled, an alias provides a nice clean URL for a path on a site.
>   However Drupal does not remove the old path (eg node/1234). The
>   problem is that you now have two URLs representing the same content.
>   This is dangerous territory for duplicate pages which can get you
>   sandboxed by the search engines!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [pathauto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) (URL Alias) which allows you to chose a particular path for your custom content add.
Enable this module and go to yourdomain/admin/config/search/path where you can add a path for your custom content type.

Add Existing system path like : node/add/document
    and Path alias as : add/document

Comment: Thanks, this is also good and can work in conjunction with Global Redirect.